# Tableau average line on chart of averages

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar plot with average values for some dimensions, let's say: weekdays. Now I want to put an average line on it - I use Analytics > Average Line. The line I get doesn't show the average for all data examples though, but the average counted from the aggregated values on the plot (avg from 7 values).
Can I get somehow the other one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put whatever your [Value] field is called on the Detail shelf. Then double click on it to edit it on the shelf

Change the expression to `Total(Avg([Value]))` where Value is the field you are displaying

Use this field for your average line, Read about **Total()** in the documentation. You may also need to edit the table calc addressing and partitioning characteristics to scope your total as desired (although the default settings often work) Read about Table Calcs in the on-line help for more info